# Magento: Tab click event

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

Anyone knows a way to listen for clicks on magento tabs with javascript on the backend, say you want to do something everytime someone clicks a tab on the edit customer page. adminhtml/tabs.js has this:

```
    tabMouseClick : function(event) {
    var tab = Event.findElement(event, 'a');

    // go directly to specified url or switch tab
    if ((tab.href.indexOf('#') != tab.href.length-1)
        && !(Element.hasClassName(tab, 'ajax'))
    ) {
        location.href = tab.href;
    }
    else {
        this.showTabContent(tab);
    }
    Event.stop(event);
},
```

But no use, anyone has any idea? I also tried using standard prototype js observer:

```
Event.observe("product_info_tabs", "click", function () 
{ alert(1); 
});
```

Did not do anything either. The solution should not modify the core, since this would add many problems with upgrades and maybe future magento versions.

Comment: Please define "no use" more precisely. The `varienTabs` handler you posted usually _is_ the place to listen for tab clicks.

Comment: As far as i can see this class is used to render the interface, i cannot find something to use to receive the click tab event.

Comment: The "something to use to receive the click" is already there, you only need to add your code to the `tabMouseClick` handler. For example: insert the line `alert("tab was clicked");` right before the `if/else` block of your post to see this in action.

Comment: well yes I could modify the core, but I cannot do this for an extension if I want to be able to upgrade magento easily.

Comment: I see, please update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To listen for clicks on Magento tabs (`varienTabs`) in the backend, you only need to add your custom observers to the existing ones. Using your example ("edit customer page" in backend) this would be:

```
var myTabs = $$("#customer_info_tabs li a.tab-item-link");
for (var i = 0; i < myTabs.length; i++) {
    Event.observe(myTabs[i], "click", function (event) {
        var tab = Event.findElement(event, "a");
        // insert your custom code here
        alert(tab.id);
        Event.stop(event);
    });
}
```

To implement custom observers without changing the core files (breaking upgradability), you could override the appropriate admin controller action.

For example, override `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::editAction()`:

```
<!-- app/code/local/My/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <My_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_Adminhtml</My_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Next, define your custom admin controller:

```
// app/code/local/My/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
require 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php';
class My_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController
{
    public editAction()
    {
        // copy of Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::editAction() code here
    } 
}
```

Finally, in the overridden action, create an additional text block containing your custom observer script and append that block to the layout. For example at the end of `editAction` insert something like this:

```
    :
    $this->loadLayout();
    $oBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var myTabs = $$("#customer_info_tabs li a.tab-item-link");
            for (var i = 0; i < myTabs.length; i++) {
                Event.observe(myTabs[i], "click", function (event) {
                    var tab = Event.findElement(event, "a");
                    alert(tab.id);
                    Event.stop(event);
                });
            }
         </script>
    ');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($oBlock);
    $this->renderLayout();
    :
```

Answer (score 0):

Old answer, but since I am here:
Magento internals fire an event when teh tab is shown.
You can simply hook into that event.

```
varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('showTab', function(arg){
            console.log(arg.tab);
        });
```

Also not needed to inject via overriding controller.
Just add in yoru own custom layout directive, and load js accordingly.